# Output shortest route shapefile using pgRouting and JSON data

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgsql

I'm interested in finding the shortest route between two sets of bike share stations (22/21 stations each) in the city of Glasgow. Note, I need to overlay the final shapefile onto an OSM basemap in QGIS I've decided to use pgRouting to achieve this goal.

So far I have a functional pgAdmin with installed pgRouting and GAUL extensions. As tested by [these instructions](https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/).

I have also the two datasets in JSON file - example below.

However, I'm having trouble developing a short script that would produce the final shapefile that we're looking for. Any advice on where to start tackling this issue?

My JSON data looks as follows;

{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "id": 8448,
    "title": "Queens Park West",
    "nearest-address": "1 Queen Square",
    "racks": null,
    "ward": "Strathbungo",
    "permanent": true
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -4.27246,
      55.83506
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "id": 8401,
    "title": "Glasgow Central Station",
    "nearest-address": "107 Hope Street",
    "racks": 10,
    "ward": "Anderston / City",
    "permanent": true
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -4.2588,
      55.860733
    ]
  }
},
]
```

}